# Chrome refuses to execute an AJAX script due to wrong MIME type

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, google-chrome

I'm trying to access a script as JSON via AJAX, which works fine on Safari and other browsers but unfortunately will not execute in Chrome. It's coming with the following error:

> Refused to execute script from '*' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Here's the request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://some_url/test.json?callback=?",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: true,
    success: function (data, status, error) {
      console.log('success', data);
    },
    error: function (data, status, error) {
      console.log('error', data, status, error);
    }
});
```

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Comment: So, what is this ressource? A JSONP script, or a JSON file? Does its MIME type match that? Apparently not. No need for a workaround, just *fix* it.

Comment: removing the callback and using dataType jsonp does not fix the issue

Comment: I meant, *fix* the *server response*.

Comment: @Bergi: what if the server is outside of the OP's control? Maybe he's trying to use an [external API such as LinkedIn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29177190/display-number-of-linkedin-shares-client-only-without-authentication).

Comment: @DanDascalescu: He should report this as a bug, because it makes the API unusable. While waiting for this to be fixed, he can use a [proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3076439/1048572) that changes mime type or content.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

By adding a callback argument, you are telling jQuery that you want to make a request for JSONP using a script element instead of a request for JSON using XMLHttpRequest.

JSONP is not JSON. It is a JavaScript program.

Change your server so it outputs the right MIME type for JSONP which is `application/javascript`.

(While you are at it, stop telling jQuery that you are expecting JSON as that is contradictory: `dataType: 'jsonp'`).

Comment: I've to use ajax between two sites. Guide me about they you are talking about to set "Change your server so it outputs the right MIME type for JSONP which is application/javascript". How to do thi

Comment: @TaimoorChangaiz — I can't tell you that. If you are generating static files, it depends on the server you are using. If you are dynamically generating the content, it depends on the programming language (and possibly framework) you are using. Try [asking a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) which describes what you have so far and exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: thanks buddy. Btw I figured out issue. I was using dynamic files

Comment: "Change your server" doesn't work if you're trying to use an [external API such as LinkedIn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29177190/display-number-of-linkedin-shares-client-only-without-authentication).

Comment: @DanDascalescu — That doesn't appear to be the case here, so it doesn't matter for this question.

Comment: @Quentin It does matter since questions are supposed to be helpful to others, not just the OP. Google pointed me here and this doesn't help my case

Comment: JSONP is a error *Refused to execute script from https because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.* ... problem crossDomain is terrible.

Comment: @KingRider — Problem: JSONP is not HTML and software which claims it is is badly written or configured.

Comment: How to do server output application/javascript? I have just file.js and that I import to html... so where to add MIME type?

Comment: @user1405338 — Depends on the server.

Comment: I have apache php 7.1

Comment: I don't know why Google pointed me here. I made a website using Django, it works fine on chrome in Windows(in normal mode), but when it comes to android devices, chrome doesn't load CSS/JS files. Same happens in incognito mode(in windows) . I gets an error in console ```Refused to apply style from 'http:*.**.***/static/css/materialize.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled```. I can't find an answer to this... @Quentin

Answer (score 59):

If your proxy server or container adds the following header when serving the .js file, it will force some browsers such as Chrome to perform strict checking of MIME types:

```
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

Remove this header to prevent Chrome performing the MIME check.

Comment: It's a bad practice not to provide the Content-Type header of resources served in web applications. 

Avoiding MIME sniffing from server-side (using the `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` header) is a good option to prevent content-sniffing attacks.

Comment: I had to add this as part of a security audit - now i don't know what to do!! :-(

Answer (score 11):

FYI, I've got the same error from Chrome console. I thought my AJAX function causing it, but I uncommented my minified script from `/javascripts/ajax-vanilla.min.js` to `/javascripts/ajax-vanilla.js`. But in reality the source file was at `/javascripts/src/ajax-vanilla.js`. So in Chrome you getting bad MIME type error even if the file cannot be found. In this case, the error message is described as `text/plain` bad MIME type.

Comment: Thank you a lot! This was my problem aswell. It was in the wrong directory.

Comment: You saved me 1 hour today champ! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

*For the record and Google search users*,
If you are a .NET Core developer, you should set the content-types manually, because their default value is null or empty:

```
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error using IIS 7.0 with a custom 404 error page, although I suspect this will happen with any 404 page. The server returned an html 404 response with a text/html mime type which could not (rightly) be executed.

Comment: We had similar issue, returned content was a 302 (because user became unauthenticated) and it didn't have a content-type at all -> non-executable.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use

```
$.getJSON(url, function(json) { ... });
```

to make the request (to Flickr's API), and I got the same MIME error.
Like the answer above suggested, adding the following code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ dataType: "jsonp" });
```

Fixed the issue and I no longer see the MIME type error in Chrome's console.

Answer (score 0):

if application is hosted on IIS, make sure Static Content is installed. Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows features on or off > Internet Information Services > World Wide Web Services > Common HTTP Features > Static Content.

I faced this problem when trying to run an existing application on a new IIS 10.0 installation