# UCWA Autodiscovery Response from Lync

Tags: autodiscovery, ucwa

I'm trying to make a UCWA application that connects to a Lync server. For now I'm just using the sandbox provided on ucwa.lync.com

I have been looking at the samples but I want to simplify it as much as possiple folowing the steps on
http://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/KeyTasks-CreateApplication

Here is what I got:

```
var url = "https://lyncdiscover.gotuc.net" ;
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: (data) => {
        alert("success");
    }
});
```

I was hoping this would return the hrefs for user and xframe, but I get a mime type error:

> Refused to execute script from '-shortened-' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not
>   executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0):

My immediate thoughts lead me to think that you mistakenly put the dataType as **jsonp** as the returned Content-Type from the server and neglect to provide a callback in the url provided.  I would lean in the direction that UCWA **probably** does not support JSONP responses and that might be close to why it is not working in your situation.

If **jsonp** is not a typo, can you explain why you want to use it instead of using a xframe for cross-domain communication?

Potentially related question: [Refused to execute script from '*' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528211/refused-to-execute-script-from-because-its-mime-type-application-json-is)