# Issue with Jquery loading json from remote site

Tags: jquery, html, css, json

I've been having this issue for awhile now and haven't found anything to help. I'm trying to load JSON from trackobot.com.

Here's my Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://trackobot.com/profile/history.json?username=still-whelp-8571&token=bybhMPvw6b6Lr77aeX3Z?callback=?',
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I keep getting this:

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://trackobot.com/profile/history.json?username=still-whelp-8571&token=…Lr77aeX3Z?callback=jQuery2130673694928875193_1432239078433&_=1432239078434' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What content does the request return?

Comment: Either Json or Jsonp i'm not sure

Comment: Looks like you're passing a jQuery id into the `callback` query param.  Not sure if that's intended or not.

Comment: @user3195968 Without seeing an example of the returned content I'm going to guess it's JSONP but you've set dataType to JSON.

Comment: I've tried to use JSONP as well and both had the same error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Refused to execute script from '\*' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528211/refused-to-execute-script-from-because-its-mime-type-application-json-is)