# If dataType is JSON why would MIME type 'application/json' be rejected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I had thought that if dataType was specified as JSON that jQuery therefore expects a JSON response.  Is that correct?  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ seems clear on the point.

In the function below I have tried specifying no dataType (for jQuery "Intelligent Guess") and explicitly to JSON (as seen below).

Both result in 
"Refused to execute script from [SNIP] because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."

This function previously worked for some years so either jQuery version changes or the headers sent from the API server must be causing?

How do I adjust so the sent MIME type 'application/json' is accepted?

```
function refresh() {
    $.post('https://api.example.com/api/v1/screenshot/create?callback=?',
        {
            'url': 'http://example.org/reports_scorecard_blank_HTMLMAKER.php?CTN=' + $('#CTN').val(),
            'dataType': "json",
            'size': 'page',
            'key': 'MY_KEY_HERE',
            'screen_width': 1900,
            'flash_delay' : 0,
            'delay' : 0,
            'instance_id' : 65,
        },
        function(remote, textStatus) {
            console.dir(remote);
            console.log('textStatus '+textStatus);
            if (remote.error) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                $('#cardMaking').hide();
                $('#error').html(remote.error).show();

                return;
            }

            if (textStatus != 'success') {
                setTimeout(function() { refresh(); }, 5 * 1000);
                return;
            }

            if (remote.queue == 0) {
                $('#cardMaking').html('DONE!');
            }
            else if (remote.queue == 1) {
                $('#cardMaking').html('< 1 minute');
            }
            else if (remote.queue > 1) {
                $('#cardMaking').html('< ' + remote.queue + ' minutes');
            }


            if (remote.status == 'finished') {
                clearInterval(interval);

                $('#final_url').html( '<i>' + (remote.final_url || $('#url').val()) + '</i>');
                $('#summary').show();
                link = 'SOME_HTML_HERE';
                $('#cardMaking').html(link);

                // now fetch image
                $.post('reports_scorecard_blank_IMAGE_FETCHER.php',
        {
            'remote_id': remote.id,
            'CTN': $('#CTN').val()
        }, function(data) {
            console.log("Fetcher response: " + data);
                }
                );

            }
            }, 'json'
    );
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528211/refused-to-execute-script-from-because-its-mime-type-application-json-is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've included `callback=?` in the URL which overrides everything else and causes jQuery to make a JSONP GET request instead of an XHR POST request.

Comment: Thank you!  Any idea why it worked as written in past?

Comment: Also- I tried just now specifying dateType as JSONP and still get same response.  Do I have to find a way to get rid of the callback in URL?

Comment: Of course you get the same response - by putting callback=? in the URL you are *implicitly* setting the dataType to jsonp. Explicitly setting it as well won't make a difference. If you want to make a non-JSONP request then yes, you have to get rid of callback=?