# Ajax JSONP refuses to execute code because of MIME type

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp, mime

I'v been trying to make a script that checks reddit page and sends back titles of posts. I am able to use

```
$( "#foo" ).load( "https://www.reddit.com/r/csgobetting/search?q=flair%3Amatch&sort=new&restrict_sr=on&t=all&feature=legacy_search #siteTable .thing .title a:even" )
```

but I have to use chrome [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) and I want to avoid it at all costs. (It gives me `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present` error in console)

other thing I tryed is

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.reddit.com/r/csgobetting/search?q=flair%3Amatch&sort=old&restrict_sr=on&t=all&feature=legacy_search",
    jsonp: "callback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){
        data=$(data).find('#siteTable > div.thing.id-t3_3m2ezw.linkflair.linkflair-match.odd.link.self > div.entry.unvoted > p.title > a ');
        $('#foo').append(  data );
    }
});
```

But it gives me error:

> Refused to execute script from 'https://www.reddit.com/r/cs...' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

I'v looked on the internet for 3 hours but couldnt find anything that would help me.

Also this is not duplicate to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528211/refused-to-execute-script-from-because-its-mime-type-application-json-is) as it didint help me.

My goal is to get page titles with links without using extensions or security disabling parameters.

Comment: *"My goal is to get page titles with links without using extensions or security disabling parameters"* Good luck. this simply isn't possible using just the browser without extensions or disabling security protocols.

Comment: @KevinB it's possible , i already gave him the answer

Comment: @Diptox from my comment: *"using just the browser"*

Comment: @KevinB I havent said "using just the browser", I jsut didint want to disbale security parameters or install extentions, everything else is fine. My goal was to make a script that I can share with people without having them install or change bs

Comment: I know, i said that, so that i can make the point in my comment. I think it would be too broad to have the question open to server-side solutions too unless you narrow it down to a specific server-side language.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Best way is cURL , download the HTML content of an URL then ECHO it to your javascript then get what you want :D , or do all of it in PHP with this great PLUGIN : https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/Selectors

Comment: I'v never worked with PHP, so I dont know how it would go.. :(

Comment: give me 5 min i will make for you a link that if you give it a parameter URL , it will return the HTML code , hope it helps you 5min be right back

Comment: do you have a server where to host the file ?

Comment: So here is the Demo LINK 
http://mouadhhsoumi.tk/stackoverflow/downloadHTMLcontent/getHTML.php?url=YOUR_URL

here is a dropbox file link to put it in your server :https://www.dropbox.com/s/pgaug9wuq2o2meb/getHTML.php?dl=0

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will try to make something out of it. I hope it works. Gonna leave this open so others can brainstorm when I test things, but i think it will solve it!

Comment: it works i tested it , here is the link that you gave in your post open it and you will see the full page :D

http://mouadhhsoumi.tk/stackoverflow/downloadHTMLcontent/getHTML.php?url=https://www.reddit.com/r/csgobetting/search?q=flair%3Amatch&sort=new&restrict_sr=on&t=all&feature=legacy_search #siteTable .thing .title a:even

Comment: It does load the page, but for some reason when i try to load that page thru ajax, it gives me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Comment: don't use jsonp 

remove those 2 lines from your ajax request : 

jsonp: "callback",
dataType: "jsonp",

Comment: Yeah tryed that.. `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: ah sorry i forget to active cross domain :p :p 1sec i fix that

Comment: I added `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` and it seem to fixed the error, im trying to get it working now, as it doesnt change anyhitng yet

Comment: that's nice , hope you are ok now :D