# AngularJs Refused to execute script because its MIME type ('image/jpeg') is not executable

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax

I'm trying to access a image on CDN server using angular JSONP get request, but the following error is coming

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://gaadicdn.com/auctions/12/DL4CAF6779/1.JPG' because its MIME type ('image/jpeg') is not executable.
```

Below is the request calling:

```
$http.jsonp('http://gaadicdn.com/auctions/12/DL4CAF6779/1.JPG').
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert(data);
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $rootScope.error = true;
                });
```

Does anybody knows the solution?

Comment: [Have a look at this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24528549/3186722)