# Cross-domain fire and forget getting MIME type ('image/png') is not executable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I have an ajax request to an external domain that posts, but throws an error saying "Refused to execute script from 'https://externaldomain.com/?sourceId=abcd' because its MIME type ('image/png') is not executable."

I don't care about the return value, I just want to fire and forget without any errors or warnings.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://externaldomain.com/?sourceId=abcd",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  crossDomain: true
});
```

The other problem is, if I change the dataType to anything besides jsonp, I get a cross-origin request blocked error.

Comment: did you try changing `dataType` to `"image/png"`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome refuses to execute an AJAX script due to wrong MIME type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528211/chrome-refuses-to-execute-an-ajax-script-due-to-wrong-mime-type)

Comment: Yes, but unless the dataType is jsonp, I get cross-domain errors "has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin xyz is therefore not allowed access.