# Twitter tracking pixel causing MIME type error

Tags: javascript, nginx, twitter

I'm trying to load [Twitter's tracking pixel](https://business.twitter.com/en/help/campaign-measurement-and-analytics/conversion-tracking-for-websites.html) on my Meteor/NodeJS website.

The code they provide is:

```js
!(function(e, t, n, s, u, a) {
    e.twq ||
        ((s = e.twq = function() {
            s.exe ? s.exe.apply(s, arguments) : s.queue.push(arguments);
        }),
        (s.version = "1.1"),
        (s.queue = []),
        (u = t.createElement(n)),
        (u.async = !0),
        (u.src = "//static.ads-twitter.com/uwt.js"),
        (document.body.appendChild(u)));
   })(window, document, "script");

twq("init", "MY-TRACKING-ID");
twq("track", "PageView");
```

It loads fine but returns the following error in the console:

> Refused to execute script from 'https://analytics.twitter.com/i/adsct?p_id=Twitter...' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

This is the exact same problem as: https://twittercommunity.com/t/analytics-tracking-pixel-error-was-blocked-due-to-mime-type-mismatch-x-content-type-options-nosniff/83583/2, but while that thread is unresolved he's running the Twitter tracking pixel on that site now, which suggests it's a server configuration issue.

Looking at the code, this [uwt.js file from Twitter](//static.ads-twitter.com/uwt.js) it requests a script from https://analytics.twitter.com/i/adsct which Chrome is preventing from running.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528211/chrome-refuses-to-execute-an-ajax-script-due-to-wrong-mime-type) suggests it's either a MIME type config issue (I'm running Nginx) or a header issue, but removing `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` and restarting Nginx had no effect.

Any idea how to fix or better troubleshoot this?

Comment: Where is "//analytics.twitter.com/i/adsct?p_id=Twitter" requested?

Comment: Take a look in the minified uwt.js file.

Comment: What is `e` within the function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**TLDR: This scary error message proves the conversion/s are actually being received by Twitter, so thankfully there's not much to worry about.**

I'm getting the same console error when implemented as per [Twitter's Google Tag Manager instructions](https://business.twitter.com/en/help/campaign-measurement-and-analytics/conversion-tracking-for-websites.html#google-tag-manager).  Clearing out cookies didn't help in my instance.  In fact, the same error shows up on Twitter's own help pages!

Here's the offending function in the minified [uwt.js](https://static.ads-twitter.com/uwt.js) script, exposed as `twttr.conversion.buildPixel()`:

```
buildPixel: function(e) {
    var t = new Image;
    t.src = e
},
```

User agents will queue up a request for the [`Image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) as soon as it's `src` property is set, and often expect a valid image in response.  Twitter's servers however provide `content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8` as a response header.

The latest version of Chrome obviously doesn't like loading `text/html` into instances of `Image`, but could probably be logging a nicer error message, especially since the response also includes a `Content-Length: 0` header indicating there's nothing to see.

Comment: Do you still get this error message in Chrome incognito mode?

Comment: This is the correct answer. Clearing cookies does not solve the issue. Incognito does not solve the issue. This is a browser security issue caused by a mismatch between the MIME type and the X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff. This issue can only be solved at the server level, by sending over the correct content-type.

Comment: No way to hide it with a try/catch or something?