# Getting Error while calling open weather Api using Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to call open weather api end point to retrieve weather data. I am using ajax call to do so . But I am unable to retrieve data ending up with error

> Refused to execute script from
>   'http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b22143fb388a8a942c07908dad1c1c90&callback=jQuery110200018843492128348682_1517942950649&_=1517942950650'
>   because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and
>   strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Screenshot of the code:

[image: Code]

Comment: Post your code...

Comment: @Tallboy please see code here https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MF8J.png

Comment: Good and effective practice is to post code inside your question rather than include it in image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome refuses to execute an AJAX script due to wrong MIME type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528211/chrome-refuses-to-execute-an-ajax-script-due-to-wrong-mime-type)

Answer (score 0):

After looking at that API endpoint, you will need to build a proxy file on your server.

You can leave your ajax request alone, but point it to `/your/domain/file.php`.

From there, inside the PHP file, make a backend server-to-server request and return the results to the client.

This will bypass the CORS restriction and the improper Mime type (chrome is preventing it from loading)

Comment: Failed to load http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Muzaffarabad&appid=ea7cda5080a1c8d5daaed5d14756d3c6: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:27481' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: when using without jsonp genrates above error and cache true does not work

Comment: You probably will need to build a proxy on your server which proxies the request from the same domain to bypass CORS. After looking at it, their jsonp doesn't return the proper MIME type and that wont work in chrome