# Google app Engine migrate to framework 2.0 wrong response content type

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, content-type

After migrating to Google app engine framework 2.0 the response content type changed from 
`text/javascript to application/json.`

This cause the error in chrome:

```
Refused to execute script from
'https://fusepointclubsdev.appspot.com/_ah/api/fusepoint/v1/editorlogin? 
callback=jQuery191035986374450586744_1526292138655&object= 
{%22user%22:%22xxx%22,%22password%22:%22yyy%22}&_=1526292138656' because its 
MIME type ('application/json') 
is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

I am using ajax:
return $.ajax({

```
method: method,
url: url,
data: data,
dataType: 'jsonp',
failQuite: failQuite,        
async: async,       
success: function (data) {
    if (data != null) {
        ....;
    }                
 }
});
```

the request URL:

```
https://fusepointclubsdev.appspot.com/_ah/api/fusepoint/v1/editorlogin? 
callback=jQuery191033183874487984477_1526290379258&object= 
{%22user%22:%22xxx%22,%22password%22:%22yyy%22}&_=1526290379259
```

web.xml:

```
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>com.fusepoint.services</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>restricted</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

The same request on api v1 was returning the correct content type.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a duplicated question, look here:

> [Chrome refuses to execute an AJAX script due to wrong MIME type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528211/chrome-refuses-to-execute-an-ajax-script-due-to-wrong-mime-type)

Content type is **application/json** and seems that should be **application/javascript**